# How to deal with suspected homework questions?

Tags: discussion

I regularly see what looks to me like homework questions ([example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/82795/64377)) and I'm never sure what is the policy about such questions on DataScienceSE:

- Currently I assume that the policy is along the lines of the [StackOverflow policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on the subject, is this a fair assumption?
- If a question looks to me like the OP didn't have "good faith attempt to solve the problem", should I vote to close it? Lack of details maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross Validated has the policy of giving helpful hints (even as posted answers) in an attempt to guide to a solution to a problem. I see no issue with Data Science taking that same stance.

Answer (score 5):

I think that's a fair position, to match SO's policy.